# Java Stream problems

Tags: java, function, java-8, java-stream

I want to use stream in java 8 , for take (filter),skip and reverse but i don't know how..

Here is my code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] array = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i <array.length ; i++) {
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(array[i]));
}
Integer firstKElements = list.size()/4;
Integer middleKelemnts = list.size()/2;
```

Now, after i filled the `ArrayList` with `integer` , i want to make a `Array` or `ArrayList` for the `firstKElements`, and then for the `middleKElements` (Example :
`[8, 4, 3, 2]` `firstKElements` is `[8]`, `middleKElements` are `[4, 3]`)

How can i do it with stream?

Comment: I assume `K` is some number? How is `firstKElements` only one element, when `middleKElements` is two elelments?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good use for streams. Just use [`List#subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) at the appropriate indexes.

Comment: Im coming from C# and i dont know how Java streams works... I want to make two Arrays , i tried this `ArrayList<Integer> first = list.stream().filter(firstKElements);`

Comment: firstKElements nad middleKElements are the lenght i need to take from the List :)

Comment: `filter` takes a Boolean predicate to filter out elements from a List. I think you are looking for `limit`

Comment: o yeah, my fault im looking for limit right but it does not work as C# and im confused

Comment: It would be recommended to find the resources necessary to learn Java streams, and show what you tried with Streams. You are welcome to [edit] your question with those attempts

Comment: @NicolasFilotto wrote it . Thanks you all guys , Java is harder than C#.

Comment: And `C#` doesn’t have the ordinary `int` datatype or what’s the reason to declare `firstKElements` and `middleKelemnts` as `Integer` variables here?

Comment: Java is not harder than C#. What you tried wouldn’t work in C# either. An integer value doesn’t magically turn into a predicate for the contained elements.

Comment: @Holger , dude if this was C# i would say int[] array1 = list.Take(2).Reverse(); and my problem is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [`skip(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) and [`limit(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) as next:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" "))
    .map(Integer::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

long firstKElements = list.size() / 4L;
long middleKelemnts = list.size() / 2L;

List<Integer> listFirstKElements = list.stream()
    .limit(firstKElements)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> listMiddleKelemnts = list.stream()
    .skip(firstKElements)
    .limit(middleKelemnts)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However for this purpose [`List#subList(fromIndex, toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) seems to be much more appropriate using `Stream` only to extract a sub part of your initial list sounds like an abusive usage of the `Stream API`.

Comment: Thanks! This works how i wanted! I want to ask you when you skip and limit, why you use L ?

Comment: because they expect a `long` not an `int`

Comment: But there is no reason to use the `L` suffix here. The result would be still the same when performing an `int` division, in fact, even declaring `firstKElements` and `middleKelemnts` as `int` variables would not make any difference.

Comment: @Holger I never said the opposite, keeping `int` when you expect `long` implies an implicit conversion and using `L` avoids it that's all, it is only a good practice nothing more

Comment: You still have an implicit conversion as you can’t change the fact, that `list.size()` returns an `int`, and it is silently promoted to `long` before the division whereas not specifying `L` causes a silent promotion after the division.

Comment: @Holger I know, I simply use the right literal corresponding to the target type, once again it is only a good habit to have, that every dev should have especially those who use IntelliJ as it is [one of the default existing warning](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/InspectionGadgets/src/inspectionDescriptions/ImplicitNumericConversion.html)

Comment: @NicolasFilotto , yes i click on the tick :) . How can i convert List to Array ?


   `List<Integer> newList =   Stream.concat(lastKelemnts.stream(),firstKElements.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

I want this List , to make it Array

Comment: `int[] values = newList.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();`

Comment: can i print array with space between elements, without bracket and commas? I mean this `[1, 2, 3, 4] `to ->`1 2 3 4` i know one way , with for loop , but i want to make it more functionallity( not only to make it, and to learn it ).

Comment: there are many ways to do that, for example with `substring`, `String result = Arrays.toString(values);` then get `result.substring(1, result.length() -1)`

Answer (score 0):

You use limit and skip as below:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter values:");
    String in = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] array = in.split(" ");
    System.out.println(array);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        list.add(Integer.parseInt(array[i]));
    }
    Integer firstKElements = list.size() / 4;
    Integer middleKelemnts = list.size() / 2;

    // limit first array to size = firstKElements
    List one = list.stream().limit(firstKElements)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(one);

    // limit middle array to size = middleKelements (ignore firstKElements)
    List two = list.stream().skip(firstKElements).limit(middleKelemnts)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(two);
```